# Clicking "an edit has been made..." button on an answer causes closure banners to disappear from question

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, closed-questions

#### To reproduce

- Navigate to a question that has been closed (e.g. as a duplicate)
- Wait for someone to edit one of the answers
- Click on the banner reading *"an edit has been made to this post"*

#### Bug

When the page is refreshed to display the new version of the edited post, the banners related to the closure of the question are no longer displayed, i.e. the one at the top labeled *"This question already has an answer here"*, as well as the one below the question labeled *"marked as duplicate by"*.

**Environment:** Windows 8.1, IE 11

Comment: Happens on all browsers.

Comment: I [reported this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247992/possible-regression-questions-duplicate-status-disappears-when-refreshing-an-e) a while ago on MSE - got closed as status-norepro :(

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for a clear, short and accurate set of steps to reproduce the issue.

I have a fix pushed - this will be in the next build.

Comment: Thanks! Silly question: when should I expect to see "the next build"? I.e. I'd like to just double-check that the reported behavior is fixed on my end. When should I do that? Is there a way to check what build is currently hosting the site? Is there a standard release schedule for builds? I did look through the Help Center and Meta but didn't find any info on that. :(

Comment: Already built out ;) - also the build number is in the footer (rev. x.y.z.n) - if it increments, it is newer. We don't have a schedule, but normally a few times a day.

Comment: Hmm...I'm confused. I attempted to verify the fix (not that I don't trust you...I just feel it's my responsibility as the bug report author to double-check the work), and I can't get the _"an edit had been made to this post"_ banner to show up, so that I can test the fix. Does the banner not show up if the person viewing the post is the one who did the editing (even in a different browser tab)? Or was the fix for this bug simply to disable that banner?

Comment: @PeterDuniho - no, it wouldn't. As you would already know you edited it... someone else needs to edit the post for the banner to come up.

Comment: Huh. If that's by design, sounds like a design mistake to me. If I've got the page loaded in a browser, and the contents of that page are now out of date, it shouldn't really matter _who_ made it out of date, I should still get the _"an edit has been made..."_ banner. Heck, just from a software quality point of view, it would be better to always show the banner regardless of who made the edit, because that's _less_ code for the implementation and so less opportunity for making a mistake (i.e. a bug).